# Put all the cells of selected row of a DataGrid in Edit Mode in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

As mentioned in the title I would like to get all the cells of selectedRow in edit mode.

So far I have tried to get the current cell and current row of the dataGrid as mentioned in the code below.

```
private void DataGrid_Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int colIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridCell))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {

        colIndex = ((DataGridCell)dep).Column.DisplayIndex;

        while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dep;
        rowIndex = FindRowIndex(row);
    }

    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGrid))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)dep;

    for (int column = 0; column < colIndex; column++)
    {
        dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[column]);
        dg.BeginEdit();
    }

}
```

The above code works like it iterates through all the cells of specified row. But at the end the last cell is put in to edit mode and so I cannot get previous cells in edit mode.

Can you suggest to do same for all the cells of selectedRow instead of last cell which I got?

Comment: Loop over all cells of selected row and set `IsEditing` property to `true` for the cell.

Comment: @RohitVats I missed it. I didn't knew that there was any property called IsEditing on a DataGridCell. Instead I was setting DataGrid's current cell. Thank you. It works fine now.

Comment: Great I have converted that to answer so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`BeginEdit()`** will put the current cell in edit mode and end edit mode of any cell already in edit mode. That's why you see last cell always in edit mode.

So, as a workaround what you can do is *Loop over all cells of selected row and set IsEditing property to true for the cell.*

Comment: Thanks once again. Yes, this answer might help someone in future.

Comment: @Rohit Vats For looping over each cell, how would you get a `Cell` object (i.e. `DataGridCell`) of the selected row?